In terms of machine code, what is the difference between linking a static library .a file vs linking a collection of .o object files?

Are the assembled instructions the same in both cases? Or the executable is totally different?

Can it possibly impact execution performance?

Could it be that linking a library generates some instruction loading overhead? (because of a bigger executable file)


I am working on a embedded C project where we run parts of the code from a RAM cached area. And when we tried to bundle this part of the code as a library in the linker, we observed some execution performance degradation. I'm trying to understand why that happened.

There should  be no difference except for the fact that if you list object files those will be linked into your binary no matter what, but the linker is typically smart enough to only pull in objects from a library as needed. So the library version could be smaller if you don't use all of the objects.

Linking a static library has no more effect on these matters than
the paper bag you bought the doughnuts in has on your health. See static libraries. If there's any
interesting effect on your program from linking a static library, it's
due to the particular object files that the linker extracted from it.

Others have described the difference in detail, and the resulting answer is "static library may not degrade your performance". So if you are seeing it, something else is going on. For example, maybe there was some link time optimization which has become hindered by bundling object files. I'd suggest taking map files from both your builds (static library vs o files) and comparing them to see what has changed - did some functions change their size, or their order, or even if something has appeared or disappeared.

Static library is just an archive containing object files. Assembled instructions are the same. The difference is which object files are linked into executable.
When linking a collection of object files, all object files are linked into executable.
When linking with a static library, only required object files from a library are linked.
For example, there are object files:
foo.o containing two symbols: foo1 and foo2:
$ nm foo.o 
0000000000000000 T foo1
0000000000000010 T foo2

bar.o containing two symbols: bar1 and bar2:
$ nm bar.o
0000000000000000 T bar1
0000000000000010 T bar2

main.o referencing to foo1:
$ nm main.o 
                 U foo1
0000000000000000 T main

Linking main.o, foo.o, bar.o together produces executable containing all four symbols:
$ gcc -o main-obj main.o foo.o bar.o
$
$ nm main-obj | grep ' T '
0000000000001160 T bar1
0000000000001170 T bar2
0000000000001174 T _fini
0000000000001140 T foo1
0000000000001150 T foo2
0000000000001000 T _init
0000000000001020 T main
0000000000001040 T _start

Placing foo.o and bar.o into a library and linking with it produces executable containing symbols from foo.o only:
$ ar rcs lib.a foo.o bar.o
$ gcc -o main-lib main.o lib.a
$
$ nm main-lib | grep ' T '
0000000000001154 T _fini
0000000000001140 T foo1
0000000000001150 T foo2
0000000000001000 T _init
0000000000001020 T main
0000000000001040 T _start

Therefore, linking a collection of object files with default flags is less optimal in terms of executable size.
However, using link-time optimization (-flto) and/or linker garbage collection (-fdata-sections, -ffunction-sections, -Wl,--gc-sections) may eliminate this difference at the cost of increasing object files size.

In terms of "machine code" - nothing.  A static library is simply a collection of object files packaged into a single file.
The difference is in the behaviour of the linker. The linker links the single object modules first and resolves any external links between them.  Then it searches the specified static libraries for object modules that resolve any remaining unresolved links, if found that object module is extracted and linked.
As such it is possible to duplicate a symbol in an object module and a static library, and the object module's definition will be linked an the library ignored.  You can use this feature to override library implementations.  Further you may have duplicate symbols in different libraries and they are resolved in the order the the libraries are presented on the linker command line.  Circular dependencies between libraries are resolvable (at least in the GNU linker) by group iteration where a list of libraries are searched in a loop until no new unresolved references are created.
